# Using [java.util] and [java.lang] in c# using ikvm

Tags: java, c#-4.0, ikvm

I am trying to access a java class via C# and I am not sure on how to pass the required parameters to instantiate it.

I need to pass an object of type [java.util.Properties] to the constructor and I need your inputs on which jar/java class files I need to convert to dll using IKVM..

From the java implementation, it looks like I need to include **java.util.dll** and **java.lang.dll**. Any help will be appreciated!

Kindly let me know if the above description is not clear!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to reference IKVm.OpenJDK.Core.dll in my c# project to start using java.util.Properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you want work with IKVM then you need ever IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll. See also in the [wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=Run_a_jar_file_on_the_fly).